# Adding event on ng-repeat element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am very new to angular :). I would like to add a simple event one form element with a particular value,  built by ng-repeat. This is how the HTML looks:

```
<div class="labels">
                        <div class="checkbox-element" ng-repeat="suggestName in $ctrl.suggests" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleSelection(suggestName, 'suggestsSelection', this)">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="suggestsSelection[]" 
                                       class="hidden" 
                                       value="{{suggestName}}"                                             
                                       ><span></span>{{suggestName}}
                            </label>                                                                
                        </div>
                        <div class="optionary hidden">
                            <br>
                            <div class="question__text">Any other?</div>
                            <label><input type="text" 
                                          ng-model="$ctrl.survey.suggest_other" 
                                          name="suggests_other1"></label><br>                    
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And the controller code:

```
vm.survey = {};

        vm.suggests = ['quality', 'price', 'habbit', 'other'];

        // selected
        vm.survey.suggestsSelection = [];

        // toggle selection for a given names
        vm.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(value, array, scope) {

            var idx = vm.survey[array].indexOf(value);

            // is currently selected
            if (idx > -1) {
            vm.survey[array].splice(idx, 1);
            }

            // is newly selected
            else {
            vm.survey[array].push(value);
            }
        };
```

What I need is to create an event that would toggle the class "hidden" from the div with class "optionary" after clicking on the last created checkbox ("other" in this case). Clicking on other checkboxes shouldn't affect the "optionary" div.

I tried with some configurations like:

```
if(scope.$last){
                $(scope).closest('.optionary').toggleClass('hidden');                 
            }
```

or similar. I don;t know what should be the way to approach the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ng-show and a control variable. Take a look.

jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24834/

```
<div ng-app class="labels" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="checkbox-element" ng-repeat="suggestName in suggests" ng-click="toggleSelection(suggestName, suggestsSelection, this)">
       <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cbSuggest[$index]" name="suggestsSelection[]" class="hidden" value="{{suggestName}}">
            <span>{{suggestName}}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="optionary hidden" ng-show="showOther">
        <br>
        <div class="question__text">Any other?</div>
        <label><input type="text" ng-model="survey.suggest_other"  name="suggests_other1"></label><br>
    </div>
</div>


var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.survey = {};
   $scope.suggests = ['quality', 'price', 'habbit', 'other'];
   $scope.cbSuggest = [];
   $scope.showOther = true;

    // selected
    $scope.survey.suggestsSelection = [];

    // toggle selection for a given names
    $scope.toggleSelection = function(value, array, scope) {
      var showOther = true;
      angular.forEach($scope.cbSuggest, function(k,v){
          if(k) {
              showOther = false;
          }
      });
      $scope.showOther = showOther;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see ng-repeat has special properties: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

The one you're interested in is `$last`. You could add `ng-change` to your checkboxes, call a function with the paramter `$last`, and that function would set a scope variable. The `hidden` class could rely on that.

Something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="suggestsSelection[]" 
       class="hidden"
       ng-change="showHidden($last)"
       value="{{suggestName}}">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.hidden = true;
$scope.showHidden = function(isLast) {
    if (isLast) $scope.hidden = false;
    else $scope.hidden = true;
}
```

And then you add `ng-class` to your div:

```
<div class="optionary" ng-class="{'hidden': hidden}">...</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be a good solution but after aplying ng-repeat throws out '{{suggestName}}' instead of the checkboxes labels, as before. How could it go wrong? :)

Comment: You shouldn't set `value` property like that, instead you should use `ng-model="suggestName"`. Edit: if you're meant to set true-value with that, then use `ng-true-value`. You can read more about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Comment: It's not working... After this change, the options are visible but clicking on them changes their value to true/false.